# Storing color and position (height and width) in an array which can be changed accordingly (bubble shooter)

Tags: collision-detection

How can I store the colors and position (i.e the position of the balls in bubble shooter game) using an array? I first tried using a simple loop but I think it won't work when I need the balls to burst so the balls should be printed using arrays. Here is my simple code

```
DrawLine( 380 , 60 ,   mx ,  my,10,  colors[BLACK]);
DrawRectangle( 1,89 ,799,500 , colors[WHITE]);
DrawRectangle(0 , 0,330 , 90 , colors[WHITE]);
DrawRectangle(430, 0, 380  , 90  , colors[WHITE]);


int zig=0;

int wide1=25;
int high1=574;

for ( high1 ; high1>=80 ; high1=high1-50){
    for (wide1 ; wide1<=780 ; wide1= wide1+50 ) {
        DrawCircle(wide1 , high1 , 25 , colors[WHITE]);
    }
    zig=zig+1;
    if (zig%2==0){
        wide1=25;
    } else {
        wide1=50;
    }
}
```

Comment: "i think when i wanted the balls to burst it wont work so the balls should be printed using arrays" it's not clear what you mean by this. What problem are you having? What behaviour do you want versus what behaviour are you seeing so far?

Answer (score 1):

Even if they looks like bubbles, they are exagons : [image]

so you can use a bidimensional array as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392621/what-is-the-best-way-to-represent-hexagonal-latice) to represent hexagons:

> The simplest way to represent a hex grid with a 2D array is to skew
>   your axes: each row of hexes is offset by half a step more than the
>   previous one. It doesn't matter whether each row is offset forward or
>   backward, as long as you're consistent about it; below, each
>   successive row is offset half a hex forward:

```
(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) (0,4)

   (1,0) (1,1) (1,2) (1,3) (1,4)

      (2,0) (2,1) (2,2) (2,3) (2,4)

         (3,0) (3,1) (3,2) (3,3) (3,4)
```

See also [Hexagonal Grids](http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/) as reference.